# Изменить поле для авторизации Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация

По умолчанию laravel (ver 10) использует для авторизации пару email и password, мне же необходимо вместо email использовать другую ячейку. Как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо. Для авторизации я использую jwt-auth.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно вместо email указать нужную ячейку в auth()->attempt(['**login**' => 'user', 'password' => 'userPassword')

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать получить пользователей из модели (на основе пользовательских полей)

```
$user = User::first();
```

И создать для них токены можно так:

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

Допольнительную информацию можете взять в
[документации](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/)